# Why is Octahemioctahedron topologically a torus?

Tags: general-topology, polyhedra

I'm afraid, that I have a very bad space vision, because I don't see, that  [Octahemioctahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahemioctahedron) is topologically a torus. Could somebody explain it for me, why is it?
[image]

---

Scene 2.

@aes:

Finally, with your help I managed to match the vertices of the polyhedron with the vertices on the topological net, thank you. The result is this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Re: the drawing with labeled points: The hexagon starting with 7-3 is 7-3-2-4 (and then the last two vertices are out of view), _not_ 7-3-1-6, which isn't part of a face at all. The hexagons go straight through the center of the diagram (they all cross each other in a line, and all of them meet in the center, but the crossings aren't counted as edges/vertices).

Comment: In your 3D diagram, 7-3-2-4-x-y is a hexagon (your flattened out picture doesn't match correctly at all).

Comment: The other three hexagons (in the 3D picture) are 8-3-1-5-x-z, 9-2-1-6-y-z, and 4-5-6-7-8-9. Use only those 4 hexagons and the 8 triangles to match it to the flattened out picture.

Comment: @aes: You are right, thank you. I've corrected the matching on my picture.

Comment: Now I see, that the squares appear as straight lines on the flattened out picture, and parallel squares correspond to parallel lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As drawn here it isn't topologically a torus. It isn't even a manifold. But if you think of it as the *image* of a map from a polygonal complex built out of eight triangles and four hexagons, with vertices and edges corresponding to those shown in your picture (i.e. no vertex at the center, and no edges where the hexagons in your picture meet) then that polygonal complex is a torus.

This is difficult to visualize, but wikipedia has an image which is a sliced open torus (if you identify the opposite edges, you get a torus):

[image: Torus fundamental domain]

If you compare carefully the way the polygons fit together in the octahemioctahedron you display with this picture (remembering that the opposite edges in this picture are supposed to be identified) you can see they match up exactly. That is, the polygons in each and the way their edges & vertices are identified match up.

This shows the polygonal complex has the structure of a manifold (you can also check this without checking it's the torus just by making sure each edge has two polygons meeting at it and that if you trace around each vertex you get a single loop of polygons) and that the manifold is a torus.

The Euler characteristic method (12 vertices - 24 edges + 12 faces = 0) mentioned in the other answer is also a good one, but you should make sure to check it's a manifold (as in the parenthetical above) and that it's orientable. Then you can conclude without actually visualizing the torus that it is in fact one, as the only oriented closed 2-manifold with zero Euler characteristic is a torus.

Comment: So those yellow things in OP's picture are _hexagons_? Ohh. It's just that some of the hexagonal faces pass through other faces. Weird.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Exactly. It took me a little while to figure out that was what was going on. I hadn't heard of these immersed (if you will) polytopes before.

Answer (score 2):

Foolproof method: use the triangulation shown in your picture to show that the Euler characteristic is 0.

Comment: Not enough foolproof:)
I see here a solid with V=13, E=36, F=32, so with Euler characteristic 9.  My result comes in the following way. I start from a [Cuboctahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron). First I divide each square face into 4 triangles, then I pull the 6 midpoints of the squares into the center of the body. The first step doesn't affect the Euler characteristic, while the second one decreases the number of the vertices by 5 (glues 6 vertices together) and the number of edges by 12 (glues each of the 24 new vertices to an other). Where is the error in this logic?

Comment: @mma It's a really weird object. The squares aren't supposed to count as faces. Instead, the yellow things are (unbent) hexagons which go straight through the center. If you count them, you'll see there are four of them (peering in through one of the "squares" you'll see a little triangular piece of each of the four). And there are 8 triangles. So there are 12 faces. The vertices & edges are the golden spheres & silver rods in your picture (i.e. don't count where the hexagons overlap). You can count these --- it's the same as for the cubeoctahedron, which has 12 vertices and 24 edges.

Comment: @mma Continuing: Your calculation is correct for the physical object, which is not a manifold and does have $\chi = 9$. But if you want to see the torus wikipedia is talking about, think of it not as an object sitting in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but as an abstract collection of polygons glued together which is then mapped (in a way that's not 1-to-1 where the hexagons overlap) into $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @aes Do you know the official name of this $\chi=9$ object?

Comment: @mma It's homotopy equivalent to a [wedge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum) of 8 spheres, corresponding to the 8 tetrahedra.